# Ember-data and MongoDB, how to handle _id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data with rails and MongoDB and am having problem with the way IDs are stored in MongoDB - in a _id field.

Ember-data will use id as the default field for ID so I tried to override it like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
    primaryKey: "_id"
    name: DS.attr "string"
    image: DS.attr "string"
```

This seems to work most of the time but in some instances I get exceptions from ember saying:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the
>   key _id but you have no mappings

I suspect this might be a bug in ember-data because it's still heavily under development, but I was trying to find a way to get to map _id to id on the server side in rails? I'm using mongoid to do the mongo mapping.

Comment: Mongoid generally aliases id to _id for you ... what problems do you have when you just leave as id?

Comment: Its mapping to ember-data where I have the problem. I get an entity from the server and the json is {_id:5008b66d330eb996c100000f} rather than {id:5008b66d330eb996c100000f}. I'm then getting a mapping error from ember-data.

Comment: I found out that my problem was really the format of the JSON response for retrieving an entity. It was like {_id: 5008b66d330eb996c100000f} when it should have been {entity: {_id: 5008b66d330eb996c100000f}}

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Mongoid here is a solution that makes it so you don't have to add a method `def id; object._id.to_s; end` to every serializer

Add the following Rails initializer

**Mongoid 3.x**

```
module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId
      alias :to_json :to_s
      alias :as_json :to_s
    end
  end
end
```

**Mongoid 4**

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```

Active Model Serializer for `Building`

```
class BuildingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

Resulting JSON

```
{
  "buildings": [
    {"id":"5338f70741727450f8000000","name":"City Hall"},    
    {"id":"5338f70741727450f8010000","name":"Firestation"}
  ]
}
```

This is a monkey patch suggested by [brentkirby](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/354#issuecomment-20913660) and updated for Mongoid 4 by [arthurnn](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/354#issuecomment-26805414)

Answer (score 3):

An other way could be to use (if possible for you) the [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers). (I think it should be close to rabl (?))

From the ember-data gihtub: https://github.com/emberjs/data:
*Out of the box support for Rails apps that follow the active_model_serializers gem's conventions*

When we began with ember-data we were crafting `as_json()`, but using the gem is definitely better :)

Comment: Absolutely & definitely the best way out of serialization in a Rails/Ember app...

Comment: @sly7_7 I'm suffering from the same problem but I'm using .NET backend instead of RoR. I'm able to produce json in the format Ember-Data expects but I still get the mappings error message. My json goes like this `{ "genres": [{"id":1, "name":"Action"}, {"id":2, "name":"Drama"}]}` Would you care to take a look in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182866/ember-data-how-do-mappings-work)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, instead of including _id in your JSON, you could craft the JSON to instead use the id method rather than the _id attribute. Ways:

You could use [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/), and the JSON could be like:

```
object @user 
attributes :id, :email
node(:full_name) {|user| "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"}
```

You could also craft the as_json method

```
class User
  def as_json(args={})
    super args.merge(:only => [:email], :methods => [:id, :full_name])
  end
end
```

Comment: Also do not forget about this workaround https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2200

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using ember.js with ember-resource and couchdb, which also stores it's IDs as `_id`.

As solution to this problem I defined a superclass for all my model classes containing a computed property to duplicate `_id` into `id` like this:

```
// get over the fact that couchdb uses _id, ember-resource uses id
id: function(key, value) {
    // map _id (couchdb) to id (ember)
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return this.get('_id');
    }
    else {
        this.set('_id', value);
        return value;
    }
}.property('_id').cacheable()
```

Maybe this could solve your problem too?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [`ActiveModel::Serializers`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Since we are using **Mongoid**, you will need to add an include statement like that (see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/benedikt/1959907) from benedikt):

```
# config/initializers/active_model_serializers.rb
Mongoid::Document.send(:include, ActiveModel::SerializerSupport)
Mongoid::Criteria.delegate(:active_model_serializer, :to => :to_a)
```

And then include your serializer. Something like that:

```
# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email
  def id
    object._id
  end 
end
```

This fixes the `_id` problem

Answer (score 1):

The second part of joscas's answer fixed the id issue for me with Rails4/Ruby2 except I had to .to_s the _id.

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email
  def id
    object._id.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mongoid3, here is the monkey patch may work for you.

https://gist.github.com/4700909

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly when this was added, but you can just tell Ember-Data that the primaryKey is _id:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id'
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is quite old but i still think my answer could help others:

If you are using ActiveModelSerializer then you just need to do this :

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     attributes :id , :name
end
```

It works all fine. I am using emberjs on the front end btw.