# Ember-Data: How do "mappings" work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, ember.js, ember-data, ember-old-router

I'm currently trying to put something together with ember + emberdata + router + asp.net web api. Most of it seem to work, however I stuck in an error message I get when ember-data tries to `findAll` through the adapter for my models.

In my backend I have a model like this (C#):

```
public class Genre {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which in my app I represent it like this using ember-data:

```
App.Genre = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr("number"),
    name: DS.attr("string")
}).reopenClass({
    url: 'api/genre'
});
```

I have also a Store defined in my App using the RESTAdapter like so:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        bulkCommit: false
    })
});
```

And the store is used in my controller as below:

```
App.GenreController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: App.store.findAll(App.Genre),
    selectedGenre: null
});
```

The router is defined as

```
App.router = Em.Router.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        //...

        genre: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/genre',
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('genre');
                }
            })
        }),

        //...
    })
})
```

When I run my application, I get the following message for every object that has this same structure:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the
>   key 0 but you have no mappings

For reference, here's the json the service is returning:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Action"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Drama"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Comedy"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Romance"
  }
]
```

I cannot tell exactly what the problem is and since the assertion is mentioning that I need mapping, I'd like to know:

1. What this mapping *is* and how to use it.
2. Since the returned json is an array, should I be using a different type of controller in my app ,or is there anything I should know about when working with this type of json in ember-data? or should I change the JsonFormatter options in the server?

Any help is welcome.

I can definitely add more information if you feel this isn't enough to understand the problem.

**EDIT**: I've changed a few things in my backend and now my `findAll()` equivalent action in the server serializes the the output as the following json:

```
{
  "genres": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Action" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Drama" },
      { "id": 3, "name": "Comedy" },
      { "id": 4, "name": "Romance" }
   ]
}
```

But I still can't get it to populate my models in the client and my error message has changed to this:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the
>   key genres but you have no mappings

Not sure what else I might be doing wrong.

The method that throws this exception is [`sideload`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L236-262) and checks for the mappings like this:

```
sideload: function (store, type, json, root) {
        var sideloadedType, mappings, loaded = {};

        loaded[root] = true;

        for (var prop in json) {
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { continue; }
            if (prop === root) { continue; }

            sideloadedType = type.typeForAssociation(prop);

            if (!sideloadedType) {
                mappings = get(this, 'mappings');
                Ember.assert("Your server returned a hash with the key " + prop + " but you have no mappings", !!mappings);
//...
```

This call `sideloadedType = type.typeForAssociation(prop);` returns `undefined` and then I get the error message. The method `typeForAssociation()` checks for the for `'associationsByName'` key which returns an empty `Ember.Map`.

Still no solution for this at the moment.

***By the way...***

My action is now like this:

```
    // GET api/genres
    public object GetGenres() {
        return new { genres = context.Genres.AsQueryable() };
    }

    // GET api/genres
    //[Queryable]
    //public IQueryable<Genre> GetGenres()
    //{
    //    return context.Genres.AsQueryable();
    //}
```

I had to remove the original implementation which gets serialized by [json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) as I could not find config options to produce a json output as Ember-Data expects ( as in `{resource_name : [json, json,...]}`). Side effect of this is that I've lost built-in OData support, but I'd like to keep it. Does anyone know how could I configure it to produce different json for a collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mapping can be defined in the DS.RESTAdapter. I think you could try to define something like this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    bulkCommit: true,
    mappings: {
      genres: App.Genre
    },
    // you can also define plurals, if there is a unregular plural
    // usually, RESTAdapter simply add a 's' for plurals.
    // for example at work we have to define something like this
    plurals: {
      business_process: 'business_processes' 
      //else it tries to fetch business_processs
    }
  }),
  revision: 4
});
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

***Update:***

At this time, this is not well documented, I don't remember if we found it by ourself reading the code, or perhaps Tom Dale pointed on it.
Anyway, here is the point for [plurals](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L205)
For the mappings, I think we were driven by the same error as you, and either we tried, either Tom teached us about this.

Comment: Both answers helped, I guess I really didn't know where to set the mappings. Now I'm gonna finally start working with the views and templates. Thanks Sylvain

Comment: Last thing on this, I couldn't find any specifics on `mappings`. Could you point out where I could have found it? If it's only in source code? It could/should be available in the readme tho.

Answer (score 8):

The `RESTAdapter` expects the returned `JSON` to be of the form:

```js
{
  "genres": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "action"
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Drama"
  }]
}
```

The tests are a good source of documentation, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/rest_adapter_test.js#L315-329

Comment: I managed to make my service to produce json on the same format but now I get the message "*Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key genres but you have no mappings*". I managed to load with a different set of controllers/models with ember 0.9.1 and no ember-data

Comment: Well, unfortunately it's not the json format, it's something else now as I'm returning the format indicated above and now I get the same message for another property and no longer for the index.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ember Data `rev. 11` and it seems that the `plurals` config in `DS.RESTAdapter.create` never works. I looked into the codes and found a solution as following:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: false
})

App.Adapter.configure('plurals', {
  series: 'series'
})
```