# return single record with ember-data find() and multiple params

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to do a find (with ember-data) on other params than the id, two params actually.

but all i get back is:

```
"Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key customer but you have no mappings".
```

After digging around in the code i see that the find method delegates to the **findQuery** method when given an hash, which create a **DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray** but I only return a single customer object in my json:

```
{"customer":{
"id":24857,"name":"Kim Fransman","id_number":"XXXX","email":"email@domain.com","type":"Person"}}
```

I can solve this by wrapping my json in a customers array and looping through them in my handlebars view but that feels very wrong.

Is there a way to do this with ember-data today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I opened a question here. Basically this is an undocumented property of the RESTAdapter that you have to configure according to your models. You'll have to define it similarly to this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    bulkCommit: true,
    mappings: {
      // All your models will have to have a mapping defined,
      // like this...
      genres: 'App.Genre'
    }
  }),
  revision: 4
});
```

Check my question here: [Ember-Data: How do "mappings" work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182866/ember-data-how-do-mappings-work)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Now I don't use that code anymore but this will probably help someone else who googles!

Comment: I'm not sure which version you are using, but on the relationship-improvements branch it seems the DS Model class needs to be quoted in the mappings object, e.g. 
`mappings: { genres: 'App.Genre' }`.