# how to define new mappings for Ember to avoid the no mapping error

Tags: ember.js, mapping

My users JSON returns the result like so:

```
{
    users: [{...}]
    some_other_data: {}
    some_other_data2 [{...}]
}
```

If i remove the other keys from the JSON result - then it'll work fine, but i really need those extra other "keys" to be included in the JSON result.

I tried to apply a solution from the answer here - [return single record with ember-data find() and multiple params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249211/return-single-record-with-ember-data-find-and-multiple-params)

But changing my code

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
    revision: 12
    adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
```

to something similar to the solution above just messes up the paths that my ember app requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for extra properties in your JSON response in ember-data.

The only 'extra' properties that are supported are `meta` and `since`, for example:

```
{
  meta: {}
  since: {}
  users: [{...}]
}
```

This extra properties can later be extracted by hooking into the `extractMeta` function of your serializer, something like this:

```
App.CustomRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractMeta: function(loader, type, json) {
    var meta, since;
    meta = json[this.configOption(type, 'meta')];
    since = json[this.configOption(type, 'since')];
    if (!meta || !since) { return; }
    Ember.set('App.metaDataForLastRequest', meta);
    Ember.set('App.sinceForLastRequest', since);
    this._super(loader, type, json);
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    serializer: App.CustomRESTSerializer
  })
});
```

IMO, if you can, you should change the JSON returned from your backend and retrieve the extra data by defining an extra model and bind it to your `User` model with a relationship like `hasMany` or `belongsTo` to make things work.

Hope it helps.