# How to set mapping on Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm beginning to work with ember-data and I have a problem to map the data

Here an exemple of my code ( i've place a jsonTest as an exemple of the data received from de backend , I don't work on the backend and I cannot modify the response from the server )

```
Clive = Ember.Application.create();
// MODEL


Clive.Deadline = DS.Model.extend({
    title : DS.attr('string'),
});

jsonTest = '{"items":[{"id":93,"title":"title","date":"14-11-2012"}]}';

// Adapter 
Clive.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    findAll : function(store,type){
        var  self = this;        
        self.didFindAll(store, type, jsonTest);
    }
});

Clive.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'Clive.adapter'
});

Clive.deadlineList = Clive.Deadline.find().get('items');
```

When I run the code I have this error :

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it
```

Here a jsfidlle with the exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/gilles/6D5BC/

Comment: Been there.. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182866/ember-data-how-do-mappings-work) will help. Also, read about the JSON format that Ember-Data likes [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "server returned a hash with key 0" thing is because didFindAll() expects a javascript object not a string. So trying again with:

```
json = {"items":[{"id":93,"title":"title","date":"14-11-2012"}]};
// -> "Your server returned a hash with the key items but you have no mapping for it"
```

Next step is to transform the object to have naming conventions that ember is expecting. Since your model is named Deadline, use the following:

```
jsonTransformed = '{"deadlines": [{"id":93,"title":"title 1","date":"14-11-2012"},{"id":94,"title":"title 2","date":"14-11-2012"}]}';
```

I've added a second record, but you get the idea. Finally you need to change how the `Clive.deadlineList` variable is being set: `Clive.Deadline.find()` returns a collection of Clive.Deadline models, so just:

```
Clive.deadlineList = Clive.Deadline.find()
console.log(Clive.deadlineList.getEach('title'));
// -> title1, title2
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle with working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/6D5BC/9/

Comment: He said he can't modify the JSON from the server.  Is there a way to alter the default key value expected by the model?

Comment: @c4p yes, with custom `adapter` and `serializer`. Not a lot about this on the internet as of now tho. Basically most apps using Ember-Data connecting to existing APIs or your own server in a scenario you can't change the JSON response, you'd have to customize the `adapter` and `serializer` within your `store`. For scenarios which allow you to change the backend (e.g. your own app) you should be find with the built-in `RESTAdapter`. In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6yMxU-_ARs&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0&index=1) video, Tom Dale gives an overview of how it should work

Comment: Thanks ! Ok , the best solution is to modify the json response

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to use the following Gem. It will just make your life easier. You wont need to generate or structure the json manually.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

For more help, have a look on this free [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

Comment: That's great, if you use Rails. Not all of us do.

Comment: @TylerEaves: Yes, you are right :). I was using Ember with Rails so that thing was in my mind