# Possible to manually apply OData parameters to result of `.AsQueryable()`?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a MVC4 WebAPI controller that returns an `IQueryable`, and therefore I can use `$filter` and friends in the URL to manipulate the result from the REST endpoint. Here's my controller:

```
public class EnrollmentController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<tblEnrollment> Get()
    {
        var context = new ProjectEntities();
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return context.tblEnrollment.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

But, like [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182866/ember-data-how-do-mappings-work), I'm wanting to make the JSON output format a little different to be friendlier with Ember Data's expected format. So I'd like to return this instead:

```
return new { enrollment = context.tblEnrollment.AsQueryable() };
```

However, that breaks OData capability because I'm not returning the `IQueryable` to the WebAPI layer. So, I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like this:

```
return new { enrollment = context.tblEnrollment.AsQueryable().ApplyOData() };
```

Which I'm sure would be way to good to be true...but is there some way to explicitly process the OData parameters against an `IQueryable` instead of letting the WebAPI layer do it implicitly on the result set returned from a `Get` method? Or is there another way to accomplish what I want here?

Incidentally, I'm stuck on EF4 for the time being, because I can't upgrade to VS2012 (and hence to .NET4.5 and hence EF5). I could theoretically upgrade to EF 4.3.1, if it would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of marking your action as [Queryable], you can add a parameter of type ODataQueryOptions and apply it manually. Here's what it might look like:

```
public class EnrollmentController : ApiController
{
    public object Get(ODataQueryOptions<tblEnrollment> query)
    {
        var context = new ProjectEntities();
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var queryResults = query.ApplyTo(context.tblEnrollment.AsQueryable());
        return new { enrollment = queryResults };
    }
}
```