# Ember model only loads last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, mongoid, ember-data

I'm trying to reproduce [Railscasts 410](http://railscasts.com/episodes/410-ember-part-2) example (called `Raffler`), changing the setup for last versions and to match my habits:

- Ember 1.0.0-rc.6
- Rails 4.0.0
- Mongoid master (4.0)
- Haml 4
- Emblem 0.3.0

In this example project, we create a simple model `Entry` that calls a small Rails Rest API.

Everything works as expected, except that calling Raffler.Entry.find() to get all entries only loads the last record.

Here is my model :

```
Raffler.Entry = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  winner: DS.attr('boolean')
```

My store :

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure('plurals', entry: 'entries')

Raffler.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 12
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
```

When calling `Raffler.Entry.find()` there's an AJAX request on `http://localhost:3000/entries` and all records are returned (so I don't think the problem is server side) :

```
{"entries":[{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001"},"name":"Foo","winner":true},{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000002"},"name":"Bar","winner":false},{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b384492cd4d286000003"},"name":"Baz","winner":true}]}
```

But only the last of these records is really loaded in the model.

Here in the JS console :

```
e=Raffler.Entry.find()
e.toArray().length
=> 1
e.objectAt(0).get('name')
=> "Baz" (always the last one)
e.objectAt(1)
=> undefined
```

Comment: what's the console result of e.toArray() ?

Comment: @Matthew Graves: An array with a single Ember object : `[Object { id="[object Object]", store=<Raffler.Store:ember330>, _reference={...}, more...}]` (shortened FF console output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found the cause of the problem (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571777/ember-data-and-mongodb-how-to-handle-id)): it was because, by default, Mongoid returns JSON with `id` in the format `{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001"}`, that Ember does not seem to understand.

By adding this serializer on my Rails `Entry` model:

```
class EntrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :winner

  def id
    object._id.to_s
  end

end
```

API request now responds this (note there's no `$oid` anymore):

```
{"entries":[{"id":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001","name":"Foo","winner":true},{"id":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000002","name":"Bar","winner":false},{"id":"51e5b384492cd4d286000003","name":"Baz","winner":true}]}
```

and Ember now loads all records :

```
Raffler.Entry.find().toArray().length
=> 3
```

**EDIT:** Note that this is a Mongoid 4 specific issue since the `$oid` notation wasn't used in earlier versions. Here is a test with an existing Rails 3.2 / Mongoid 3.0 app :

```
1.9.3-p194 :006 > Mongoid::VERSION
 => "3.0.23"
1.9.3-p194 :007 > Node.first.id.as_json
 => "507521e68df996381b00151b"
```

Now with my Ember test under Rails 4 / Mongoid 4 :

```
2.0.0-p247 :007 > Mongoid::VERSION
 => "4.0.0"
2.0.0-p247 :008 > Entry.first.id.as_json
 => {"$oid"=>"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001"}
```

I've added the `mongoid` tag to my question.

The Serializer solution works well but it means creating a serializer for every single Mongoid model...just to return to Mongoid 3 behavior...not that clean...

Answer (score 0):

You have posted that Raffler.Entry.find() returns this :

```
{"entries":[{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001"},"name":"Foo","winner":true},{"id":   {"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000002"},"name":"Bar","winner":false},{"id":{"$oid":"51e5b384492cd4d286000003"},"name":"Baz","winner":true}]}
```

than :

```
e=Raffler.Entry.find()
e.entries.length
=> 3
e.entries[0]
=> {"id":{"$oid":"51e5b35b492cd4d286000001"},"name":"Foo","winner":true}
e.entries[0].name
=> "Foo"
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: in the case of this question `Raffler.Entry.find()` is javascript not rails

Comment: I am also asking in context of javascript. Are these output values are wrong that I have posted here? Have you tried these in your console.

Comment: there are not wrong, but in the question for example doing `e.objectAt(0).get('name')` is ember.js notation and not the same as doing `e.entries[0].name`

Comment: `e.entries` doesn't even exists. `Raffler.Entry.find()` does not return the JSON but it generates an API request whose JSON is the output. The problem is that the Rails API returns 3 entries and Ember only loads the last one.